# finding number of even numbered words

Tags: r

I an trying to find number of even numbered words using R lang. Can someone help.
Say I have a sentence as 'My name is XXXXX'. here we have 2 even numbered words. So I want to calculate this count of 2.

Comment: There are 3 even numbered words, not 2

Comment: What do you mean even numbered? If you mean the number of characters then `sum(nchar(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]) %% 2 == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rs integer division, `%/%`

```
str <- "My name is XXXXX"
length(unlist(strsplit(str, " "))) %/% 2

[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to interpret this, but if you mean the number to be the order of the word in the sentence, first you have to split it, then get the indices

```
string <- "My name is XXXX"
words <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))
count <- sum(seq_along(words) %% 2 == 0)
count
# [1] 2
```

Comment: #erocoar's is simplier. my fingers just like `seq_along(x) %% N == 0` for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. This actually counts the number words with even number of letters.

```
x <- "My name is XXXXX"
sum(nchar(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))) %% 2 == 0 )

# [1] 3
```

Here is with `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(unlist(str_split(x, " "))) %% 2 == 0 )
```